# how to fix ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

how to fix this problem the code gives me 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

languages = OrderedDict()

languages['jen'] = 'python'
languages['sarah'] = 'c'
languages['edward'] = 'ruby'
languages['phil'] = 'python'

for name, language in languages:
    print(name.title() + "'s favorite language is " + 
    language.title() + ".")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['too many values to unpack', iterating over a dict. key=>string, value=>list](//stackoverflow.com/q/5466618/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `odict_iterator` (what you get when using an `OrderedDict` in a `for` loop like this) only yields its keys, not the key/value pairs. Use the `items` method to get those:

```
for name, language in languages.items():
    ...
```

(This is true for any kind of `dict`; a `dict` provides a `dictkey_iterator`, but `OrderedDict`, I suppose, has its own to provide its keys in original insertion order.)

(As of Python 3.7, a `dictkey_iterator` will *also* yield keys in insertion order, but when `OrderedDict` was introduced, this was the defining difference.)